# Create shortest log organizer

Tags: code-golf

Create the shortest script that organizes all the logs by month and date.

## Rules

**Syntax**

```
organize <folder to scan> <folder to place logs>
```

- folder cannot be root
- the two folder should be different and not contain one another

**Behaviour**

The script should scan all the *.log files in `<folder to scan>` and copy them to `<folder to place logs>` in sub-folders corresponding to the year and month of the last modified  time of the log file, named like `year_month`.

Example:

```
organize /var/log/apache2 /temp/logs
```

would give folder structure like this:

```
/temp/logs/
|-- 2014_01
|-- 2014_02
|-- 2014_03
|-- 2014_04
|-- 2014_05
```

**Languages, environment**

All languages and OSs are permitted but need to be specified.

But since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question, script languages (python, bash, windows batch) will be more fit from the start.

Comment: Are we sorting them based on create date, modified date, filename, etc? If name, how is the name formatted?

Comment: @Geobits A edited to make it more clear, "sub-folders corresponding to the year and month of the last modified time of the log file"

Comment: Is target folder exists or it should be created first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bash - 79 bytes

```
stat -c" $2/-%n-%y" $1/*.log|awk -F- '{d=$1$3"_"$4;system("mkdir"d";cp "$2d)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch - 104 bytes

```
@cmd/von/c"for /r %1 %%a in (*.log)do @set a=%%~ta&set a=!a:~6,4!_!a:~3,2!&mkdir %2\!a!&copy %%a %2\!a!"
```

Comment: What if there are more than one log file per month?

Comment: @Kondybas that would be fine.

Comment: @Kondybas Do you mean more than one log file _with the same name_ per month?

Comment: Eeeh, oops! You're right :)

Answer (score 2):

### Bourne Shell / FreeBSD 9.2+ - 92(83) bytes

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -lD"%Y_%m" $1/*.log|cut -wf6-|while read A B;do mkdir $2/$A;cp $1/$B $2/$A;done
```

Answer (score 2):

## Cobra - 223

**OS: Any with Mono/.NET**

Because this is the perfect task for an obscure compiled language! < /sarcasm>

```cobra
class P
    def main
        a,b=CobraCore.commandLineArgs[1:]
        for f in Directory.getFiles(a,'*.log')
            m=b+File.getLastWriteTime(f).toString('yyy_MM')
            Directory.createDirectory(m)
            File.copy(f,m+f[f.lastIndexOf('/'):],true)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell (124 bytes)

```
Get-ChildItem $($s+"\*.log")|%{$n=$d+"\"+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy_MM");if(!(Test-Path $n)){md $n}mi $($s+$_.Name) $n}
```

Has the added bonus of scanning for only .log files in the given folder if there are multiple file types. If not, then I can knock this down to 112. $s is the full source folder path, and $d is the destination folder path.